# Почему не срабатывает column-gap нужным образом?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой список, нужно чтобы между элементами было расстояние в 35 пикселей. У меня прописан параметр column-gap 35 пикселей, но он не срабатывает, наоборот немного даже делает это расстояние шире. Почему так происходит?

```css
.section-playlist__category-list {
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: 35px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="section-playlist__category-list">
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="post-punk">
    <label class="label" for="post-punk">
                Постпанк
              </label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="hardcore">
    <label class="label" for="hardcore">
                Хардкор
              </label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="punk-rock">
    <label class="label" for="punk-rock">
                Панк-рок
              </label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="rock">
    <label class="label" for="rock">
                Рок
              </label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="Progressive-rock">
    <label class="label" for="Progressive-rock">
                Прогрессивный рок
              </label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="Electronic-music">
    <label class="label" for="Electronic-music">
                Электронная музыка
              </label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="Classical-music">
    <label class="label" for="Classical-music">
                Классическая музыка
              </label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="Nature-sounds">
    <label class="label" for="Nature-sounds">
                Звуки природы и шум города
              </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Все правильно работает...

Comment: @Air я задал ширину в 35 пикселей, там на картинке видно что примерно 200-300 пикселей. Или я не правильно понимаю как это свойство работает?

Comment: ты  все верно понимаешь, просто ты не понимаешь где у тя что находиться...  задай все элементам  разные цвета фона и увидишь, где у тя что находиться и почему я говорю, что там все верно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ширина элементов li равна ширине самого широкого из них.
2. Ширина всего списка у Вас не задана и равна ширине родителя.
3. column-gap -- значение "не меньше", если Вы уменьшите родителя (или окно браузера) и не будет возможности обеспечить нужную ширину column-gap -- количество колонок уменьшится.

```css
.section-playlist__category-list {
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: 35px;
  max-width: fit-content;
}

li.section-playlist__category-item {
  border: 1px dotted darkred;
}
```

```html
<ul class="section-playlist__category-list">
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="post-punk">
    <label class="label" for="post-punk">1</label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="hardcore">
    <label class="label" for="hardcore">12</label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="punk-rock">
    <label class="label" for="punk-rock">1234</label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="rock">
    <label class="label" for="rock">12345</label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="Progressive-rock">
    <label class="label" for="Progressive-rock">1234</label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="Electronic-music">
    <label class="label" for="Electronic-music">123</label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="Classical-music">
    <label class="label" for="Classical-music">12</label>
  </li>
  <li class="section-playlist__category-item">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-checkbox" name="music" id="Nature-sounds">
    <label class="label" for="Nature-sounds">1</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```